# How can I flatten out a folder in Windows 7, assuming all file names are different?

Tags: windows

For example, say that I have the following folder hierarchy:

```
Folder1
   File1
   Folder2
      File2
   Folder3
      File3
      Folder4
         File4
```

I want to perform some command that results in:

```
Folder1
   File1
   File2
   File3
   File4
```

or something similar. I'm not very familiar with Windows, so I would appreciate as much detail as possible in the answer.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing program to do this for you, or a piece of code (what programming language) that does this?

Comment: @MattBall: I'm looking for the easiest possible way of doing this. Ideally, this would be opening up a terminal and inputting some command. Again, I'm not very experienced with Windows, so please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to extract the contents of many folders at once?](https://superuser.com/questions/523816/easiest-way-to-extract-the-contents-of-many-folders-at-once)

Answer (score 37):

The absolute easiest way is to enter the common root folder and do a search for all files (i.e. search for *). When all files are found, mark all files, press Ctrl + X and navigate to the common root folder again. Now press Ctrl + V to paste all the files into the root folder. When finished, delete all subdirectories.

I do not know if this can be done as a batch job.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, but I tried it with 40k files and it crashed the explorer process.

Comment: The total commander answer seems easier to me.

Comment: May or may not apply to OPs problem exactly, but great example of also leveraging the "dumb" tools in our toolbox :)

Answer (score 19):

I used this powershell approach in the end when I needed to flatten a large hierarchical structure (in my case pngs) :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\sourcefolder -Recurse -Filter "*.png" | Copy-Item -destination C:\destinationfolder\
```

Comment: For flattening maybe Move-Item is better suited?

Answer (score 4):

windows exe:
http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_flatfolder/

or AHK:

```
fileselectfolder,MyFold,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}
SetWorkingDir, %MyFold%
loop, *.*,0,1
{
  parentpath := RegExReplace(A_LoopFileDir,"\\","-")
  ;StringReplace, parentpath, A_LoopFileDir, \,-,All
  newname = %parentpath%-%A_LoopFileName%
  ;msgbox %newname%
  If a_loopfiledir <>
    filemove, %a_loopfilefullpath%,%newname%
}

loop, %myfold%\*.*,2,1
  fileremovedir, %a_loopfilefullpath%,1

exitapp
```

or use [Directory Opus](http://gpsoft.com.au/help/opus10/default.htm#!Documents/Flat_View.htm)

or [Powershell](http://dreamlusion.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/tip-use-powershell-to-flattern-your-folders-batch-rename/)

```
(ls -r -include *.jpg) | % { mv -literal $_ $_.Name.Insert(0, [String]::Format("{0} - ", $_.Directory.Name))}
```

or [Batch](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/command-line-fun-how-to-flatten-a-folder-hierarchy/) (as mentioned above)

or the manual search, cut and paste as mentioned above

There are many ways, depending on your skill and inclinations you can choose any of these, and refine according to your needs.

You might need this [Remove Empty Directories](http://www.jonasjohn.de/red.htm) after the above operation

Comment: powershell command is short and good working

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to flatten dir manually from time to time, **Total Commander** is perfect.

In Total Commander:
Goto to your dir you want to flatten. In menu click **Commands > Branch View**. And you see it all flattened, you can move/copy it to another folder.

If you need to tinker a bit with filenames:
Select all files in flattened view, in menu go to **Files > Multi-Rename Tool**.
Here you can add some info from the path to actual filenames using "Rename mask", you just need to use plugin tag/button there, search & replace feature and the little foolder button, which lets you to make some last edits to filenames in text editor. May sound complicated, but really the easiest way IMO :)

Comment: What is Windows Commander?  Do you mean Total Commander?

Comment: Exactly :) Been using it for 10 years, name was Windows Commander back then. Edited out

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. Wouldn't work for for 40k small files though :( consumed a lot of CPU for 10 mins then came up with repeated 'couldnt create file' errors.

Comment: CPU usage and implied slowness is unfortunate but understandable:) The error is something else.. might be bad naming, total commander bug or just TC's inability to handle this many files. I would try renaming smaller number of files first or use newer version of TC

Comment: @teejay, I had to fish for the details of your suggestion, but I finally managed to make it. I used the expander2 plugin to extract parts of the path and make them the prefix of the file name. You might want to add some details for the next guy. Tx.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple with a command-line option for those not super technically inclined.

1. Create a file somewhere called "flatten.cmd"
2. Open that file in Notepad
3. In the file, place the following:

   ```
   FOR /R {SourcePath} %%G IN (*.mp3) DO move "%%G" {Destination}
   ```
4. Replace "{SourcePath}" with the folder you want to flatten.  In your case "c:\Folder1"
5. Replace "{Destination"} with the folder you want the files moved to.  In your case also "c:\Folder1".  The code should now look like:

   ```
   FOR /R c:\Folder1 %%G IN (*.mp3) DO move "%%G" c:\Folder1
   ```
6. Open up a command line window.  Can do this a number of ways, but this is fast:

   - Click the Start button
   - Click All Programs
   - Click Accessories
   - Click Command Prompt
7. In the command line window, type:

   ```
   cd {folder where you put the flatten.cmd file}
   flatten
   ```

And that will do it (Windows 8+)  I just did that to flatten a folder of 10,000 music files. Works like a charm.

You can find the options for the FOR command-line utility at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

using a batch script (off the top of my head):

Look up the [FOR command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php)

The first line moves all the files from the subdirectories up to the root
The second delete the the sub folders

```
for /f %f in ('dir "c:\folder\*" /s/b/a-d') do if not %~ff"=="c:\folder" move "%f" "c:\folder"
for /f %f in ('dir "c:\folder\*" /s/b/ad') do if not "%~ff"=="c:\folder" rd /s/q "%f"
```

Comment: so I have to open up a terminal and input these commands, making sure that I replace 'folder' with the appropriate path? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to write it in a script yes. OTOH .....

Comment: Can this be generalized and attached to a context menu action?  I'd love to be able to right-click on a file, click "Flatten File", then have all the files within it moved up to the folder's level.  Deleting the folder after would be nice too.

Comment: yes it can put it intoo a batch file with %1 as folder name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162415/adding-context-menu-to-windows-explorer-to-run-bat-files

Comment: -Perhaps you can help with this http://superuser.com/q/552768/59747

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can also use xxcopy (www.xxcopy.com) tool, its xcopy on steriods (sort-of). With this tool you can "flatten" the files in folders into one folder.

c:> xxcopy /source-folders /flatten /SG

Just read this link:
http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm

Cheers.