# Easiest way to extract the contents of many folders at once?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

In Windows 7, I have a directory of folders which each contain files as their contents.  Is there any way to extract all of the contents of each the folders to a separate location other than cutting and pasting the content one folder at a time?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you want to move the contents of a source directory and all of its sub-directories to a *single* destination directory (i.e. flatten the folder structure), it's very easy and you don't even need to bother with the command line.

Just go to the top-level source folder (whose contents you want to copy), and in the Windows Explorer search box type ***** (just a star or asterisk). This will display every file and sub-folder under the source folder. Now just sort by Type to group all files together, select them all, then cut/copy and paste in the destination dir.

If you have hidden and system files as well, under Organize → Folder and search options → View tab make sure *Show hidden files...* is selected, and *Hide protected operating system files* is unchecked.

Comment: This, my friend, is why I go to SU as often as I can. DAMN FINE

Comment: The real life-hack +1

Comment: Great answer, Would never have thought of this, I was toying with XCOPY and things and was moments away from cracking out AHK. +1.

Comment: Hmm I just tried it with Windows 10 and the folders got preserved...

Comment: @JohnAndrews: Nope, still works fine in all versions of Win10 as long as you select only the files.

Comment: This is a good answer but please add a warning: if some of the files have identical names across subfolders, and you say "yes" to the replace all question, you will lose files.  The way to avoid this is to COPY rather than CUT.

Comment: Did not work for me in W/11 if I understand the instructions.  I have one folder that only consists of numerous  folders of zipped files (name ends with .zip). Searching * the main folder results in all these sub-folders being shown, but selecting them all and choosing "Extract all" only results in the option to extract the folder that the cursor is only when I right click on to choose Extract all.

Comment: However,  right-click on the selected files and  choosing  "7-Zip > Extract to" worked fine, thank God. And thanks for the help SU has often provided.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Windows Command Prompt for running a command:

```
move C:\path\to\folder\*\* C:\path\to\folder\
```

I am not 100% certain about dashes, but \ or / should definetely work. The above command will move all files from all folders in C:\path\to\folder to C:\path\to\folder.

Comment: ill play around with it. i figured there was a command prompt solution im assuming for all of them id use the wildcard '*'

Comment: Be warned that this will clobber any duplicate filenames.