# Flatten directory structure

Tags: windows-7

I have a bunch folders within folders. Like this

```
Root Folder
    -- Folder 1
    -- Folder 2
    -- Folder 3
    -- Folder 4
```

I want to collapse all folders so that all files under folder1, folder 2, folder 3, ... folder n exist under root folder.

What is the quickest way to do this in windows?

Comment: It depends, how would you want to handle duplicate file names?

Answer (score 30):

You can flatten in Windows Explorer by navigating to the folder you wish to flatten and searching for `System.Kind:<>folder` to exclude folders from the results.

You can then select all the files with CTRL+A and copy and paste them into a new folder. Note that Windows Explorer will ask you how to deal with duplicate filenames.

[image]

Comment: note that for this to work you need to type "folder" in the corresponding localized translation (for example, in italian is `System.Kind:<>cartella`)

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Such a great a solution, allowed to copy all the photos under the DCIM folder on my card  from the resulting search folder and then upload all easily to Google Photos

Comment: This is a hell of a tip. Great stuff.

Comment: absolutely brilliant solution

Answer (score 24):

There's no reason to use special tools or even scripting. Just use the search function in Explorer.

1. Open the folder you wish to flatten in Explorer.
2. Create a new folder, select all files (but not folders), and drag them to that folder (This will avoid getting two copies of those files.)
3. In the search box (the one on the right of the address bar), type in `*` and press Enter.
4. After the list populates, right click and select all, then right click and Cut.
5. Press the back button to get back to the original folder, then right-click and paste.
6. If you have any duplicate names, you will be prompted on how to deal with this. Choose the most appropriate option for your use case. (I would assume it would be to copy both files.) To avoid being prompted again, be sure to apply this to all files with the checkbox at the bottom.
7. Select all folders, make sure they are empty by looking at the popup about the number of files selected, and then delete them.

If you would rather have a script so you can just start it and forget it, that can also be done. The command to replace `mv *\* .` is pretty easy (`for /r %f in (*.*) do @move "%~f" .`) but I'm sure you'd like to handle duplicates, without leaving them behind as in @Nicole Hamilton's answer. Appending a number to the filename of duplicates is probably the easiest way to do it.

Copy and paste the following batch file into Notepad and save it as "flatten.cmd" (including the quotation marks):

```
@echo off
cd "%~1"
md tempryfolder
move *.* tempryfolder
for /r %%f in ("*.*") do call :START "%%~f"
for /r /d %%f in (*.*) do rd "%%~f" 
GOTO :EOF
:START
setlocal
If exist "%~n1%~x1" set /a num=2
:LOOP
If exist "%~n1%num%%~x1" (
    set /a num+=1
    goto loop
)
move "%~1" "%~n1%num%%~x1"
```

To use the script, simply drag the folder you wish to flatten on top of it.

Comment: Similar but easier to understand: https://superuser.com/a/523854/433830

Comment: Note: this script is essentially a fork bomb. I'm using it on a folder with thousands of subdirectories and tens of thousands of subfiles and the memory footprint is slowly increasing. I don't think I'm going to run into OOM issues, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Nzall I have no problem believing that it could do that, but I would blame Microsoft, not my code. All I do is call a subroutine in the batch file multiple times. And I never run more than one at time: each subroutine runs until completion, running only one process at a time. How much memory are we talking about being used?

Comment: @trlkly At one point it went up to 2 GB, although I did have a quite large amount of folders and subfolders, around 75,000 files and thousands of folders. A few moments after it dropped back down to around 8-900 MB. There were loads of duplicate files though. I was flattening 12 copies of a 7,500 file Javascript library so I could test how certain software would handle a folder with tens of thousands of files.

Comment: @Nzall That's incredibly weird to me. Nothing the script does should do that. It's one subroutine that reuses a single variable to increment the file. I may have to ask what could cause such large memory usage on SO or something.

Comment: I can't use this script to flatten multiple folders at once, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @trlkly when I drag multiple folders to the cmd file, only one folder is flattened, is there any way to flatten them all at the same time with a script?

Comment: @SherifKhalifa Sure! The script would have to be modified slightly, Add `:TOP` as the second line of the script, below `@echo off`. Then add the line `if "%~2" == "" Shift & GOTO :TOP` above the line `GOTO :EOF`. That should make the script repeat itself for every folder you give it.

Comment: @trlkly I did exactly as you said, but still one folder is flattened then the script end.

Comment: @SherifKhalifa Oops. I messed up that line. It should be `if NOT "%~2" == "" Shift & GOTO :TOP`

Comment: @trlkly Thanks a lot, its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is easy with a Unix shell.  Here's what you could do with my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) (including the [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm).)  You could do something very similar with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) bash.

```
mv *\* .
```

If your directory is really huge, it's possible that could wildcard into too long a command line for Windows to pass to a child process.  (The Windows [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) call limits the argument list to 32K Unicode characters.)  But the C shell has no limit internally, so you could iterate over the whole list this way:

```
foreach i ( *\* )
   mv $i .
end
```

To @MarkAllen's point above, this kind of assumes there are no duplicate names.  If there are, the later copies in the list will overwrite the older ones.  If that's a concern, you could iterate over the files, `mv`'ing them only if you're not overwriting.  The `:t` operator is the [tail operator](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/39-PathnameEditing.htm).  The `-e` operator is the [file exists test](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/28-FileSystemTests.htm).

```
foreach i ( *\* )
   if ( -e $i:t ) then
      echo -2 $i not moved because it already exists
   else
      mv $i .
   end
end
```

This still leaves the empty directories, which maybe you don't want after they've been emptied.  That could be the next iteration if it mattered.

Comment: Using cygwin 
>mv *\* .
mv: cannot stat `**': No such file or directory

Comment: In Cygwin `bash`, `mv */* .` works for me.

Comment: Some people are so fixed in UNIXism... If you really want to do scripting in Windows 7, there's PowerShell, you don't need some bogus bash simulator like Cygwin.

Comment: You don't even need PowerShell. The regular command line still exists and can do the same things. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

i m using this one - in order to reduce my folders
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nick7ikin/bash_flatten_folder/master/flatten_folder.sh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: it s about giving the reputation to the author. Ironic, denying/down voting a solution that isn't using the "feature" overwriting files with the same name or having interruption behaviors.