# extract all .jpg files from all .zip and .rar files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: zip, extract, rar

I think I've prettu much said it all. I want to create a .bat that lets me extract all files with a certain extrnsion from all .rar and .zip files in a folder, all together into another folder.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: 
[Easiest way to extract the contents of many folders at once?](https://superuser.com/questions/523816/easiest-way-to-extract-the-contents-of-many-folders-at-once)

It may not be exactly what you asked for, but such a solution would be far easier than writing a .bat file. Sort by type and select .jpg.

Comment: The linked won't work for RAR files.