# Putting code into registry command key

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-registry

I'm trying to do what's done in this question, but I want to attach it to a context menu on Directory so I can right-click on "Flatten Folder" and have it do it for me.  That is, bring all the individual files within that folder up to the current directory, then delete the empty directory.

[How can I flatten out a folder in Windows 7, assuming all file names are different?](https://superuser.com/q/496765/59747)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  In the registry command key I've got:

```
 cmd /K "for /f %f in ('dir "%1\*" /s/b/a-d') do if not %~ff"=="%1" move "%f" "%1"
&& for /f %f in ('dir "%1\*" /s/b/ad') do if not "%~ff"=="%1" rd /s/q "%f" pause"
```

EDIT: I have the context menu option, but when I click it I get an error saying that the foldername application is not found.

UPDATED My registry change looks like this:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Flatten Folder]
@="Flatten Folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Flatten Folder\command]
@="cmd /K \"for /f %f in ('dir \"%1\\*\" /s/b/a-d') do if not %~ff\"==\"%1\" move \"%f\" \"%1\""
```

Still no dice, but no error either.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain -See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the line in `command` is not executed through `cmd.exe` – it is executed through Explorer, which does not understand cmd.exe's built-in `for` command. You will need to put your script in a separate file (e.g. `flatten.cmd`) and run that. (Note that you will need to change `%f` to `%%f` then.)

Comment: Any way to do this without an external file?  Just through the registry?

Comment: Why is that a requirement? /// I can't remember right now, but `cmd /?` will list two options for running arbitrary command lines.

Comment: Not a REQUIREMENT per se.  This whole thing is a convenience for myself.  I'd like to be able to quickly deploy this solution on all my PCs is all, and one .reg file would be really sweet.

Comment: Try `cmd /c` or `cmd /k` then. (I can never remember which is which...)

Comment: Ok, found that, see edit.

Comment: Can you provide any further insite?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this topic is a few months old but here is my take on the command as regards to a context menu:

The script by itself:

```
(FOR /f "usebackq delims==" %%F IN (`DIR "%1" /a-d/b/s`) DO IF NOT EXIST "%1\%%~nxF" MOVE "%%F" "%1") && (FOR /f "usebackq delims==" %%F IN (`DIR "%1" /ad/b/s ^| SORT /r`) DO RD "%%F")
```

As a .REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\FlattenFolder]
@="Flatten Folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\FlattenFolder\command]
@="CMD.EXE /c (FOR /f \"usebackq delims==\" %%F IN (`DIR \"%1\" /a-d/b/s`) DO IF NOT EXIST \"%1\\%%~nxF\" MOVE \"%%F\" \"%1\") && (FOR /f \"usebackq delims==\" %%F IN (`DIR \"%1\" /ad/b/s ^| SORT /r`) DO RD \"%%F\")"
```

This is tested and working on a Win 7 setup. First of all, the script will NOT move a file to the root directory if there is already a file with that name. Secondly, the script then, in reverse, removes all empty directories, skipping any that might not be empty due to a naming conflict. I believe the issue @MAW74656 was having is due to spaces in the pathnames. The `"usebackq delims=="` addresses this problem.

The plus side of this implementation is that it works. It does not touch same-named files. It will not remove a directory unless it is empty.